# Making uniform imageviews appear in nested linearlayout objects

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am using a series of ImageButtons with TextView objects as captions. I want to display the images in a uniform size, filling the width of the screen (the UI is forced into Landscape mode).
My XML layout includes the following:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonHolidays"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/holidays"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="chooseType"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/hagim" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/EditTextHoliday"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:onClick="chooseType"
                android:background="@color/White"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:text="@string/holidays" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonPeople"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/people"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="chooseType"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/people" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/editTextPeople"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:onClick="chooseType"
                android:background="@color/White"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:text="@string/professions" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

As far as I can tell, the two vertical LinearLayout objects contain object configured with precisely the same parameters, except for the text and the actual image object.  The images objects are exactly the same size.  Nonetheless, the UI shows the following:

[image: Screenshot]

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `weights` to avoid this. You have to set the width of both `LinearLayouts` to 0dp and set a weight of 1. Now both child views will take up each 50%  of the width of the parent view (Which is a `LinearLayout` I assume. Otherwise this won't work).

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonHolidays"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/holidays"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="chooseType"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/hagim" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/EditTextHoliday"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:onClick="chooseType"
                android:background="@color/White"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:text="@string/holidays" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonPeople"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/people"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="chooseType"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/people" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/editTextPeople"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:onClick="chooseType"
                android:background="@color/White"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:text="@string/professions" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: OK, that helps, but I still have gray padding above and below the images, despite the fact that I set the LinearLayout height to wrap_content (likewise for the children)

Answer (score 0):

Hard-coding the width of the ImageButton produces the desired effect.  Not as elegant or flexible as I would like, but it works on several platforms, so I guess I can live with it.

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/chooser_bottom_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonVegFruit"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:contentDescription="@string/vegetables"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="chooseType"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/fruitveg" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/EditTextVegFruit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/White"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:onClick="chooseType"
                android:text="@string/VegFruit"
                android:textColor="@color/Black" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/chooser_bottom_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonClothes"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:contentDescription="@string/clothing"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="chooseType"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/clothes" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/EditTextClothes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/White"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:onClick="chooseType"
                android:text="@string/clothing"
                android:textColor="@color/Black" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```